# Scale a Plane to fit a Frustum or Grid Cell

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to create a function taking a plane in 3d space, and returning a plane which will fit in its entirety inside one section of a grid on the screen.

The grid on the screen is fixed and is defined by either divisions in X and Y, or by a set of lines across the screen.

The original plane can be any size or orientation on the screen, though it will never take the whole screen.

I am working in Unity3.5.2f2 with C#. I have posted this on SO as it is quite heavily math based as opposed to just Unity general knowledge. Ideally a solution will not use external libraries, though it is a possibility.

I have a few methods in mind and would appreciate any input;

1. Project the plane to screen space, get the min/max x and y values of the mesh, (bounding box), use this to calculate a scale xform (using difference in height/length of mesh to that of a screen division). Re-project into world space, after snapping two edges of the mesh to a selected division.
2. As the divisions are rectangular in nature, create several view frustums, and come up with some method of scaling/translating the plane in 3d space to fit the frustum.

Function prototype would be;

```
Plane adjustPlaneToFitScreens(Plane _plane)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't used it but [GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) might be useful. And maybe this [answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/143025/more-questions-on-generating-camera-frustrum.html) from Unity Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using method 01. above. Unity provided several handy functions making the math easy, and calculating scaling and translation in pixel/screen space was far easier than in 3d space while having to take into account view angle / FOV.

There are issues with the re-projection into world after the scaling, but this particular application doesnt have the camera moving when viewing the scaled object, so the issues are not actually noticeable in black box